# Migrate GeoServer 2.8.3 to 2.12.1?

Tags: geoserver, configuration, migration

I have all my data and services (WMS, WFS, WMTS) in GeoServer 2.8 (workspaces, shapefiles, etc.) and I have to migrate to GeoServer 2.12.1.

What things do I have to consider to do that?

I mean files (data_dir), PostgreSQL databases, PostGIS.

Comment: How is your current GeoServer configured?

Comment: It is configured with docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of your existing data directory (you have moved it out of the installation directory, of course) and then add the new war file to the tomcat webapps directory and wait for it to restart.

Comment: I need just move old data directory geoserver to new data directory geoserver?

Comment: Yes that is all

Comment: And What about database? Do I have to migrate database data?

Comment: not unless you want to